# Why is the cookie not removed with php?

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to remove a cookie with php but it won't work

```
setcookie("user", 'abc', time()-3600, '/', 'subdomain.tomline.nl', false, true);
setcookie("hash", 'abc', time()-3600, '/', 'subdomain.tomline.nl', false, true);
```

It's set with the following code, and the file where it is being set is in the same directory as the file where it has to be removed.

```
setcookie("user", $_POST['mail'], time()+7*24*60*60, '/', 'subdomain.tomline.nl', false, true);
setcookie("hash", $encryptedpw, time()+7*24*60*60, '/', 'subdomain.tomline.nl', false, true);
```

For privacy reasons I have changed the subdomain. The site is not meant to be publicly visible yet.
The cookie is being set successfully but when I want to remove it it still exists and still has the value of the set cookie, not even 'abc' what it's said to have in the remove script.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `time() - 3600` to delete cookies. You have no control over the user's clock, and that's what their browser will use to compare the cookie's expiration date to local time. Particularly if they're more than one timezone away from you.

Set an absolute "can't possibly be using this as a time" value, such as `Jan 2 1970 00:00:00` for the date/time.

Comment: but this never fail your test case as OP said because he is testing in his own end

Comment: This is good advice, however, if icant's clock is correctly set, then won't it not affect testing?

Comment: @Dbz: There's no "correctly" here. If this is a remote server (which is implied by his accessing it via an actual domain), then it could be set to just about any timezone, which may or may not match the OP's.

Comment: The awkward part is that [the official PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) recommend using `time() - 3600` to delete cookies, even though it's not reliable. Oops.

Comment: It's a bad design on the part of the cookie spec. There should have been an explicit "this cookie must be deleted" syntax defined, not a hacked-in "set its expiry date in the past and hope the user's clock is reasonably correct"

Comment: But it still doesn't work when I set the expire time to Jan 2 1970 00:00:00

Comment: try sending just "1000" for the time, since the time value is a timestamp, not a string. As well, use something like Firebug to see exactly what's going back and forth in the cookie header. If you don't see your 'abc' value coming out of the server, then something's wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
  session_destroy();
```

is one idea.

Try setting the path if the URLs are different.

Comment: Seriously? It's not a solution at all. You don't delete cookies with `session_destroy()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting it to `'abc'` You can set it to just be blank `''` and that should remove the cookie as long as you are coming from a matching URL